# Why is the image not changing in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, server, phaser-framework

I tried loading an image for the background of my game.

```
let gameState = {};

function preload() {
  this.load.image('background', 'assets/background.png');
}

function create() {
  gameState.background = this.add.tileSprite(480, 270, 'background').setScale(0.5);
}

function update() {

}

let config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 960,
  height: 540,
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
    arcade: {
      gravity: { y: 500 },
      debug: false
    }
  },
  scene: {
    preload,
    create,
    update
  }
};

let game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

However, if I remove the lines where the image is loaded and added, the image still stays on the screen even though I haven't mentioned the image anywhere in the code.

How do I remove the image?

Comment: What is the version of the Phaser do you use? I assume that it's 3rd version but I need to ask anyway :)

Comment: I made a simple demo and I can't see this problem https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-flower-tb4sm

Comment: @artanik it's Phaser 3

Comment: @artanik I'm using MAMP for my server, do you think that could be causing the problem?

Comment: I don't know, but if so, then this is very strange behavior. Maybe your js is cached because code looks fine.

Comment: @artanik You were right, the js was getting cached but I found the solution on stackoverflow. Thanks!